# There is a way to check if a model field contains a substring?

Tags: python, sql, django

I wanted to know if I can do things like this:

```
full_string = "12345"
substring = "123"
Model.objects.filter.contains(field = substring)
```

More or less like this.
In summary I want to search for a substring, not the string itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Django [contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#contains) and [icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#icontains)

Answer (score 4):

you can use contain and icontain for case sensitive/insensitive strings.

Case sensitive:

```
Model.objects.filter.contains(field__contains = substring)
```

Case insensitive:

```
Model.objects.filter.icontains(field__icontains = substring)
```

note the double underscore!

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
model_name.field.objects.filter(field__contains=substring)
model_name.field.objects.filter(field__icontains=substring)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged here because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what the code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful for other users also as well as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the $regex operator to match a substring with a value in a field.

For a model, person (using mongoose), having name as a field, we can search,

```
    let your_regular_expression = new RegExp(substring);
    person.find({name: { $regex : your_regular_expression}});
```

Similar thing can be done with native mongodb.
The link to mongodb documentation is below, you can visit there to know more
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: The question is about Django and python because it has those tags. This answer is not about python or Django.